# How do I remove all styles from an element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
body{
    font-family: Arial;
}
div{
    color: red;
    margin: 20px;
    background: blue;
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

```
<div id="div1">this should be styled with a blue background, 
               red text, and 17px Arial font</div>

<div id="div2">this should have no background, default font, etc. </div>
```

How can I remove all style and all inherited styles of `#div2` with jQuery?

Remove only all style #div2, keep style #div1

Comment: <<How remove all style and all style Inherited (body...ect...) of #div2 = jQuery>>  Only for div2 ??? What do you mean by "= jQuery"?

Comment: @trong, I edited your question as an attempt to save it.  Are the descriptions in the `div`s your desired outcome, or do you want all elements to have the default styles?  I assumed the former, because it doesn't contradict.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand that was a nice attempt  :)

Comment: To answer your question, you have to override style rules for this specific element, you can use jquery css() method

Comment: I can't add an answer here, but I would like to point out, that you cannot do what you are trying to achieve, you are using a general selector here,so using `div{}` will apply to all div elements, you are using an id here, so use an `element#id {}` selector instead

Comment: Honest, I'd love to see a good answer to this question, but it technically shouldn't be reopened because it doesn't satisfy `Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work`.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand I casted a re open vote, I just thought we can give OP a chance, but after casting a re open vote I changed my mind and I commented

Comment: @roasted Remove only all style #div2, keep style #div1

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand you just have to override style for this specific element, this is the answer.

Comment: @roasted, okay.  Wasn't sure if there was some obscure hack (a custom CSS reset sheet targeting a specific class?).

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand if you find an other way, maybe provided by a crazy dark ninja let me know, i'd be interrested to know it too   ;)

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand this seems to work in all major browsers (IE/FF/chrome/safari/opera not tested) even not fully tested: http://jsfiddle.net/T2Zhh/       `var targetedElement = document.getElementById("div2"),
     rulesCSS = document.defaultView
            .getComputedStyle(targetedElement);
for(var i=0, z= rulesCSS.length;i<z;i++)
    $(targetedElement).css(rulesCSS[i],'inherit');`

Comment: @roasted, that works except for the styles on `body` are being passed through.  Any way to get access to the user agent stylesheet in the code?  That's the most correct method, if possible.  (tested Chrome dev)

Comment: Ya because font-family setted as inherit as no effect. We should for all CSS rules get the default value and then apply it to the targeted element. I think it is possible though quite oversized IMO. Ha, and for the user agent stylesheet, this could be great but i don't know for instance if possible, could be maybe.

Answer (score 5):

To remove the style tag simply select the **style** tag and **remove** it

```
$("style").remove();
```

[jQuery Remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

I think its better to use CSS id selector to achieve your goal instead of removing styles from a tag using jQuery:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial;
}

#div1 {
    color: red;
    margin: 20px;
    background: blue;
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

Comment: By looking at the quality of the question, I think you need to spoon feed him by writing the answer in a bit detail

Comment: Native: `var st = document.getElementsByTagName("style"); for(var i=0,len=st.length;i<len;i++){ st[i].parentNode.removeChild(st[i])};`

Comment: This will remove style for div1 too but anyway, seeing the poor quality of the question +1

Comment: I would give a -1, but the question contradicted itself.  It appears that this isn't the desired outcome, though, so please either provide a solution that results in removing the styles on only `#div2`, or delete your answer.

Comment: remove only all style #div2, keep style #div1